# Optional field is not visible by Typescript in object spread operator even if the value is set for this field

Tags: typescript

This code works:

```
interface IFoo {
  x: number | null;
}

interface IBar {
  x: number;
}

const foo: IFoo = {x: null};
if (foo.x != null) {
  const bar: IBar = { ...foo };
}
```

However the following code fails with compilation error (the only difference is `x?`):

```
interface IFoo {
  x?: number | null;
}

interface IBar {
  x: number;
}

const foo: IFoo = {x: null};
if (foo.x != null) {
  const bar: IBar = { ...foo };
}
```

Error is:

```
Type '{ x?: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IBar'.
  Property 'x' is optional in type '{ x?: number; }' but required in type 'IBar'.
```

The code could be fixed by explicitly setting `x` in the object: `{ ...foo, x: foo.x }`

The question: is TS correct here that `foo.x != null` is not enough to verify existence of field `x`? If yes, why? If no, is it a limitation of TS types or a bug?

Comment: Typescript will narrow the field type not the whole object type. So this works `const bar: IBar = { x: foo.x };` Your original code does not work with strictNullChecks either (without this option `number | null` is just `number` anyway)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, yes, I know that we can explicitly specify `x` and this will work. However, isn't `?` a part of field type? Why TS is unable to narrow `number?` to `number` but it is able to narrow `number | null` to `number` after explicit check? Is it by design?

Comment: It narrows both cases, and in both cases you get an error on the spread if `strictNullChecks` are on (https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8BQyyAHgFzIgCuAtgEbTIA+FlANqwNz4C+++okWIhSoAQnCh5CJclTrQuvfAkwgAzmGQxs5DNmQBePGRbtuXYDGQAKbZgB0xZAEIjVdgEopRFes20JXXFJI1xkewi7ZHMeIA) Without strict null checks. `number | null` is just `number`, essentially `null` is ignored, and you don't get an error in the first case because `IFoo` and `IBar` are the same while in the second case the field is optional and thus the types are not compatibile.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarifying, makes sense now.